# How to extract request from jqXHR?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Using jQuery I can POST a `searchString` to server using this code.

```
    $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: _config.api.invokeUrl + '/foo',
    headers: {
    Authorization: authToken
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({"Search": searchString}),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: completeRequest,
    error: function ajaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ....
    }
});
```

On **success**, the `completeRequest` function is called.

```
function completeRequest(result, status, request) {
    // request is the jqXHR
    console.log('### Request ###\n', request);
    ...
}
```

The server might return an empty JSON in `result`. I want to be able to display the search did not yield anything for some `searchString`. How can I get that from `request`?

Comment: I do not really understand your problem. Why not JSON.parse(result) and check if array length is 0?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff The problem is to display which ```searchString``` caused ```result``` to be an empty JSON. BTW, ```result``` is an object in my case. ```JSON.parse(result)``` was not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**request** object doesn't give you the data you are passing while sending in the request. You need to manually assign data to the request object before sending the actual request.

You can make use of **beforeSend** method of JQuery **AJAX**.

```js
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: _config.api.invokeUrl + '/foo',
    headers: {
    Authorization: authToken
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({"Search": searchString}),
    beforeSend: function(req, settings) {
      req._data = settings.data;
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: completeRequest,
    error: function ajaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ....
    }
});

function completeRequest(result, status, request) {
    // request is the jqXHR
    console.log('### Request ###\n', request._data);
    ...
}
```

Here in the **beforeSend** method assign your data to the req object from the ajax settings object.